# how to use an associated file with the exe

Tags: c#, file

I want to know how to get information like the file path from a file if you open the file like this:
[image: from explorer (image)]
So i want the info about the file when you open the file using my program.

I have tried to use an OpenFileDialog, it works, but that's very slow, and doesn't look nice.

So, to be a little more clear, I mean when you open it from file explorer, or something similar.

Comment: your question seems unclear, please clarify what is requirement here

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have tried tu use an OpenFileDialog, it works, but that's very slow, and doesn't look nice

Comment: " if you open the file like this"? Like a picture of something that we can't even really identify? What? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: i mean when you open it from file explorer, or something similar

Comment: It is unclear if you mean mime-type association during a launch, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Program.cs you can Change `static void Main()` to `static void Main(string[] args)`

In `args` you are getting parameters used at the start of your program.
When you are now connecting `.ex` with your exe (set your exe as Default for `*.ex`), `args` will containing the path to your file, which gets double clicked.

You could take a look at this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cb20e19t.aspx).